# What does .speed in jquery do?

Tags: jquery

I just don't understand what .speed does in jquery.

jQuery.com says "Description: Creates an object containing a set of properties ready to be used in the definition of custom animations."

I'm not quite understanding what this means.

Comment: With regard to what specifically? If you have a problem understanding the docs at least provide a link to which doc and method it is

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.speed/  I'm just having a bit trouble understanding what this method exactly does.